# Can async/await still deadlock if ConfigureAwait(false) is used?

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

According to [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/) a deadlock can occur with async/await under particular scenarios.

However, can a deadlock still occur if I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` always?

For instance: `task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Instead of: `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

Comment: Side note: It's "configure await", not "configure task". The `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` doesn't have any affect because there's no `await` to configure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it still can deadlock, `ConfigureAwait(false)` will have to be implemented in all the nested awaits, some of which you may not have control over.

The best approach is not to rely on it, just don't mix synchronous and `async` calls, let *Async/Await* propagate.

The only sure-fire way (and controversially) to make sure it wont deadlock (without `await`) is to *offload* / *Wrap* it to another task and `Wait` that, or be in a framework that doesn't have a *SynchronizationContext*

Answer (score 5):

It can still deadlock if whatever is going to complete `task` or any further nested operations have captured whatever your current context is, if that context is tied to a specific thread - because you're calling `GetResult` *using that thread* and blocking, making it unavailable for others to use still.

Just use `await`. It's `await` that can *release* your current context.

Answer (score 2):

As the name implies, `ConfigureAwait()` only affects an asynchronous `await`. It has no effect on synchronous waits like `Task.Wait()`, `Task.Result` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` means roughly "I don't care what thread the code after this async await will be resumed on", so if the original thread (more accurately `SynchronizationContext`) is blocked by something it will still continue on a different thread. But a synchronous wait like `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` doesn't ever switch threads.